# Using jquery html() method to get width of dynamic text needs timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width

I'm trying to use a technique that I've seen elsewhere to quickly insert a dom node with some dynamic text in order to get the width of a div. However, immediately after the html() call, the result of the width() method, gives me, I think, unformatted width. A little while later I can get the width with the formatted text. What gives here? Is this the delay in painting? Is there a better way to do this, like with inline styles or something? Or am I completely missing a concept?

```
var htmlStr = "<span id='userFeedbackText' class='user-feedback-text'>" + f + "</span>";

_feedbackEl.html(htmlStr);
_feedbackEl.show();
console.log($("#userFeedbackText").outerWidth()); // 238

window.setTimeout(function () {
  console.log($("#userFeedbackText").outerWidth()); // 458 
}, 500);
```

EDIT: OK, well I got around the problem, by using css visibility setting to hidden, so that fixes the problem. But I'd still like to know the underlying mechanics in this specific example. Thanks

EDIT2: I've stripped the app down to the bare essentials. Looks like it's because the dynamic text is a font from google fonts, referenced remotely. So, I'm guessing here, the first width is unstyled, then it takes a small amount of time for the browser to render the text in the font, so the width changes. See here http://theade.com/stacko/ in Chrome or Safari (sporadic) on Mac Mavericks, Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/theade/msyme/ is sporadic too, Firefox on Mac seems to get it right first time.

Comment: I'm not seeing it [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/adDxq/), so it might be something with styles being applied.  Do you have an example we can see?

Comment: blurd - thanks for responding and trying it out. See response above. Cheers!

Comment: This definitely has to do with the fonts.  When the node is added, the source for `Sigmar One` is fetched.  After the fetch, the node is resized.